# Background color of nested elements not working

Tags: css

I set the background color of the outer div (`question-template`) to blue, but it is not displayed. Why?

A demo of it:

```css
.question-template {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: blue;
}

.question {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}

.participants {
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="question-template">
        <div class="participants">234</div>
        <div class="question">Some lorem ipsum text</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to add [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) to the outer `div`'s style:

```
.question-template {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

---

```css
.question-template {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: auto;
}
.question {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
.participants {
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="question-template">
        <div class="participants">234</div>
        <div class="question">Some lorem ipsum text</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Now when I specify the width of the question-template and increase the length of the question, the text goes down below the participants div. How can I makes it stay on the same line?

Comment: You can use 
display:inline-block.

Answer (score 8):

It's because both of your child elements are floated left. This means that the container won't stretch to the full height needed to contain the child elements.

To solve this you need to add a [`clearfix`](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) class such as this to your CSS:

```
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

And then add the class to your HTML like this:

```
<div class="question-template clearfix">
```

---

```css
.question-template {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: blue;
}

.clearfix:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.question {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}

.participants {
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="question-template clearfix">
        <div class="participants">234</div>
        <div class="question">Some lorem ipsum text</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Define  your **parent div** `.question-template` with [`overflow: hidden;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow):

```css
.question-template {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.question {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}

.participants {
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="question-template">
    <div class="participants">234</div>
    <div class="question">Some lorem ipsum text</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

Or add a [`clear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) div to the parent:

```css
.question-template {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: blue;
}

.clr {
    clear: both;
}

.question {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}

.participants {
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="question-template">
    <div class="participants">234</div>
    <div class="question">Some lorem ipsum text</div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add [`overflow: auto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) to `.question-template`:

```css
.question-template {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: auto;
}

.question {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}

.participants {
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="question-template">
    <div class="participants">234</div>
    <div class="question">Some lorem ipsum text</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply a clear the float on the parent div to make sure that it occupies the inner elements.
You could either insert a `<div style="clear:left;"></div>` before the parent  closes or apply a clearfix  class on the parent div.

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
​
```

Then you just add the clearfix class to the parent div

```
...    
<div class="question-template clearfix">
...
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4zjtp/8/)

Answer (score 0):

check your `display` property, maybe its `inline`? change it to `block` or something else.

Answer (score -2):

Use fixed height for `<div>` element.
It will be like this

```
 .question-template {
    width: auto;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
 }
 .question {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    color: white;
 }
 .participants {
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
 }
```

Comment: You can add overflow:hidden to the .question-template  class. In this way parent class .question-template  will try to accommodate as per child elements and occupies the own dimensions.